# ngrok, Failed to complete tunnel connection

Tags: ngrok

I downloaded ngrok on my PC, but when entering one of the following addresses it shows me the following error.

command :ngrok http 80

- http://b378568afdf7.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:90
- https://b378568afdf7.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:90

**ERROR**

`GET /favicon.ico               502 Bad Gateway`

`GET /                          502 Bad Gateway`

Error page

`The error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:80: connectex: A connection cannot be established as the destination computer expressly denied that connection.`

I was researching and one of the solutions I found was to remove the firewall protection, but it didn't work. I appreciate your attention and help

Answer (score 0):

Change the command to

```
ngrok http 90
```

if you want to run on port 90.